# How to find an elements value using "getElementById()"?

Tags: javascript, getelementbyid

```
function demo() {
var y=document.getElementById("count");
if(y="0") {
alert("There's nothing on list");
}
else {
document.getElementById("count").innerHTML="0";
alert("List sent.");
}
}
</script>
<p>List values: <span id="count">0</span></p>
```

I've used `count++` so when anyone inputs something the value increases. Is there a way to check the value of the count and return an alert based on what it is? I've tried using different amounts of `=` and comparing y to another variable with value 0, but no prevail.

Comment: `<span>`s have `innerHTML` and `innerText`/`textContent`, not value.

Comment: Thanks, I missed that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read content inside element using `innerHTML`

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/TU726/)

```
var y=document.getElementById("count").innerHTML;
```

Comment: Thanks, this works as long as there are two `=`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.  Your `(y = "0")` needs to be `(y == "0")` and you need to use innerHTML (which you are using in one part of your code, but not the other).

```
function demo() {
    var y=document.getElementById("count").innerHTML;
    if(y == "0") {
        alert("There's nothing on list");
    }
    else {
        document.getElementById("count").innerHTML="0";
        alert("List sent.");
    }
}
</script>
<p>List values: <span id="count">0</span></p>
```

Comment: Yeah, I just noticed the missing `=`. Thanks for answering.